# How to check String contain bold , italic or underline word using apache Tika

Tags: java, pdf, apache-tika

I am extracting data from pdf file which contains normal text and bold, italic and underline words. I am using apache Tika and PDFTextStripper class for that. I am reading whole pdf line by line and storing it in `String[] arryOfLine`.

Is there any way by which we can find if Particular string contains bold, italic and underline word?

Comment: Ask Apache Tika for the HTML version rather than the Plain Text version, then check for `<b>` and `<i>` tags in the html? http://tika.apache.org/1.15/examples.html#Parsing_to_XHTML

Comment: @Gagravarr what about underline words?

Comment: Apache Tika has a command line app, which is a single runnable jar, perfect for testing and debugging. Just run that in `--xhtml` mode on your PDF and you'll see what you do and don't get!